# File opened successfully but reads result in "Bad file descriptor" error and stat shows filesize zero

Tags: c, linux

I'm working on an assignment where we're supposed to crypt-analyze a PDF that had been encrypted with a poor encryption algorithm.

The code supplied by the prof creates the encrypted file with `fd=open(filename, O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR)`.

In my code to attempt decryption I open that file with `fd_in=open(file, O_RDONLY)`.

The problem is that when I try to read in from the file I'm getting a "Bad file descriptor" error. I used stat to attempt to get more information about what the file descriptor "thought" about the file that had been opened and it shows that the file is of length 0 when it is actually a few hundred KB.

The debug code I'm using is:

```
if (0 > (len = read(fd_in, (char*)&read_buff, BITE))) {    // BITE is defined as 8
  printf("Error occured grabbing first bite of %s.\n", file);
  printf("%s.\n", strerror(errno));

  struct stat fileStat;
  int stat = fstat(fd_in, &fileStat);

  printf("fstat returned: %d.\n", stat);      // Consistently printing 0
  printf("Information for %s\n",file);
  printf("---------------------------\n");
  printf("File Size: \t\t%d bytes\n",fileStat.st_size);
  printf("Number of Links: \t%d\n",fileStat.st_nlink);
  printf("File inode: \t\t%d\n",fileStat.st_ino);

  printf("File Permissions: \t");
  printf( (S_ISDIR(fileStat.st_mode)) ? "d" : "-");
  printf( (fileStat.st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? "r" : "-");
  printf( (fileStat.st_mode & S_IWUSR) ? "w" : "-");
  printf( (fileStat.st_mode & S_IXUSR) ? "x" : "-");
  printf( (fileStat.st_mode & S_IRGRP) ? "r" : "-");
  printf( (fileStat.st_mode & S_IWGRP) ? "w" : "-");
  printf( (fileStat.st_mode & S_IXGRP) ? "x" : "-");
  printf( (fileStat.st_mode & S_IROTH) ? "r" : "-");
  printf( (fileStat.st_mode & S_IWOTH) ? "w" : "-");
  printf( (fileStat.st_mode & S_IXOTH) ? "x" : "-");
  printf("\n\n");

  return 1;
```

}

The result I'm getting is:

```
Error occured grabbing first bite of enc.pdf.
Bad file descriptor.
Information for enc.pdf
---------------------------
File Size:      0 bytes
Number of Links:    1
File inode:         16441996
File Permissions:   -rw-------
```

ls reports the file as

```
-rw-------  1 matt  matt   157887 Oct 29 03:01 enc.pdf
```

---

The code related to opening the file:

```
int fd_in=open(file, O_RDONLY);
if(fd_in<0) {
   printf("Failed to open the input file %s.\n", file);
   return 1;
} else {
    printf("File open, descriptor is: %d.\n", fd_in);
}
```

This has been consistently printing out the value 3 for the filed descriptor.

There were some questions about read_buff.  The encryption/decryption process involves XORing the values that are read.  Because of this the buffer is declared as a `unsigned long long` and in order to read into it I take the address and cast it to (char*).  This tactic is straight out of the prof's code for creating the encrypted file.

I even added an else with a printf to verify the file descriptor was coming out valid.  At the moment it seems to be conistently `3` which is definitely not `-1`

Comment: Can you post the code in which you define `file` and open `fd_in`?

Comment: Opening the encrypted file with vim in hex mode works fine.  First byte or so matches my hand calculations of what I expect to see.

Comment: @onon15: fd_in is already mentioned above(`int fd_in=open(file, O_RDONLY)`).  File comes from command line argument `char* file = argv[1]`

Comment: @Matt, IIRC `printf()` can update `errno` so move the `strerror(errno)` output to before the `file` output to ensure you are getting the exact cause of failure. Also, what is the value of `fd_in`?

Comment: @hmjd: Just tested that.  Does not seem to be relevant.  I also tried setting `errno` to a few random values before the read to verify that the error message didn't change.  Pretty confident it is set by `read(..)`

Comment: Is the file open by any another program at the same time?  The `fd_in` file description should be a simple integer (3 would be typical), can you display that please?  A common error is to get ( ) precedence wrong in the `open` when nesting in an `if`, resulting in the fd being 1 or 0 (stdout or stdin).

Comment: 1 Is the application doing things in parallel: is it multithreaded? 2 How is `read_buff` declared?

Comment: Do you have permission to open the file? Did you checked if you can open the file? Did the open() return -1?
How about just use fopen()?

Comment: you're judicious about checking the result of read(). pardon the question, but the code isn't here, so.. are you just as prudent in checking the return result of the open() ? I.e. is fd_in even valid immediately after open() (because according to the error message, it isn't).

Comment: What error does fstat return?

Comment: @cdarke, I added an else to my check after open and it is consistently returning 3 as the file descriptor

Comment: @alk, not doing anything at all close to that.  Will add details about read_buff to the question above.

Comment: @WhozCraig I added the pertinent code to the question above.

Comment: 3 Does `fd_in` still has the same value (as returned by calling `open()`) after the `read()` failed? 4 Does the first call to `read()` fail?

Comment: @alk, This is the first read.  I need the header to calculate the encryption key, this would be followed by a read loop to decode the rest.  Strangely enough, printing the file descriptor in my error handling code now shows shows the FD as 11 when it started as 3 like every other run.

Comment: Ok, so I conclude the code in between the `open()` (giving `fd_in` as 3) and the `read(11,...)` somehow corrupts the stack and with this the value for `fd_in`, changing it from `3` to `11`.

Comment: @alk, Yeah, I'm trying to track it down right now.  I'll update the question either with a final solution or more detail if I don't find it.

Comment: @alk Stupid mistake using a `<=` where a `<` was warranted when writing to an array.  If you want the accepted answer type one up and I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: By experience seeing an `<=` or `>=` alway makes me nervous ... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might like to check whether the stack gets corrupted in between the calls to `open()`and `read()`, so that the value of the file descriptor `fd_in` will be changed.

Comment: Anyone who stumbles across this answer should see the comments to the question for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You neglect to check the result of various operators. I'm pretty much certain `fd_in == -1` during the code listed above.

To open a data file using low-level I/O, you need to do something like the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

...

    int  fd;

    do {
        fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY);
    } while (fd == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        const char *const errmsg = strerror(errno);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", filename, errmsg);
        exit(1);
    }
```

This is because [`open()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/open.2.html) can always be interrupted.

[`read()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/read.2.html) can also be interrupted, but usually it just returns a short count.

No, you cannot just say "*but it normally will read all that I ask, I'll fix that later if it happens*", because it really depends on the system details -- in particular, on what filesystem the file happens to reside on. Running on a different system will yield different results -- not to mention if instead of a file it happens to be a named pipe or a character device. Only an idiot will assume `read()` will always (or even usually) read all you ask it to.

The robust approach is to use a helper function, perhaps something along the lines of

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* Read between minimum and maximum bytes (inclusive)
 * from descriptor to buffer. Save the number of bytes
 * read into *bytes if bytes is not NULL.
 * The function returns 0 if successful, errno error otherwise.
 * If there is less input than minimum bytes, the function
 * will return ENOENT.
*/
static inline int readfd(const int descriptor,
                         void *const buffer,
                         const size_t minimum,
                         const size_t maximum,
                         size_t *const bytes)
{
    size_t   have = 0;
    ssize_t  n;

    while (have < minimum) {

        n = read(descriptor, (char *)buffer + have, maximum - have);
        if (n > (ssize_t)0) {
            have += n;
            if (bytes)
                *bytes = have;

        } else
        if (n == (ssize_t)0) {
            /* EOF, and have < minimum. */
            return errno = ENOENT;

        } else
        if (n != (ssize_t)-1) {
            /* A rare I/O error (Linux kernel bug). */
            return errno = EIO;

        } else
        if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EAGAIN) {
            /* Nonblocking descriptor; ouch. Busy-loop. */
            sched_yield();

        } else
        if (errno != EINTR)
            return errno;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The function will read between `minimum` and `maximum` bytes, inclusive, to the specified `buffer` using the specified file `descriptor`. If successful, it will return 0, and a nonzero `errno` otherwise. It will return `ENOENT` if there is not enough data to fulfill the minimum.

It does work even on nonblocking descriptors, by busy-looping on the nonblocking descriptor (just yielding the current time slice each time it retries and fails). That means it is not recommended to be used with nonblocking descriptors, but if you need to for some strange reason, you *can*. You just should not need to. (In fact, I personally drop that bit -- `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK` check and `sched_yield()` -- so I'll notice and fix my code to use the proper approach if the descriptor is or has to be nonblocking.)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this should be a comment. Cannot comment from here.
What is read_buff? Why do you cast to char* ?

*if* read_buff is defined as `char *read_buff;` then `(fd, &read_buff, LEN);` could perform a buffer oveflow, overwriting your automatic variables.

Comment: `read_buff` is an `unsigned long long` so I can xor it later as part of the decryption hence taking the address of and casting to `char*`